# yarn add results in command failed

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm trying to install [google cloud print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-print):

```
yarn add cloud-print
```

but I get this message:

```
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git
Directory: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/sentify/repo/sentify-ab/firebase/app
Output:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.".
    info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/sentify/repo/sentify-ab/firebase/app/yarn-error.log".
    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

What does this mean? I don't have write permissions to the repo? That is true, but I just created my own branch with `git branch sahand; git checkout sahand`. Why can't I write to my own branch?

EDIT: I granted myself write permission to the repo, but I still get the same message.

Comment: The error message is about not being able to access `ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git`. You probably didn't configure your SSH keys to be able to access GitHub using SSH.

Comment: Thanks axiac. What ssh keys are you talking about and how do I configure them?